# Matlab systems of differential equations solution using syms

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the following equations in terms of X(s) and Y(s). However, its says cannot find an explicit solution. What am I doing wrong? Hope anybody could help me. Thank you.

```
%Time domain equations:
%eq1 = x'+4y'-x = cos(t)
%eq2 = 3x' + y' = 0

syms X(s) Y(s) s

%Laplace transform
eq1 = s*X(s)+4*s*Y(s)-X(s)==s/((s^2)+1);
eq2 = 3*s*X(s)+s*Y(s)==0;

solve([eq1 eq2])
```

Comment: have you considered that there may not be an explicit solution?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Always a valid thought, but in this case I think there is: `eq1 - 4*eq2 = -11*s*X(s)-X(s) = s/((s^2)+1)` so `X(s) = s/((-11*s-1)*((s^2)+1)`, and `Y(s)` follows

Comment: @AnderBiguri Actually I have already solved the system manually and found the solutions pointed out by Wolfie. However, my problem is implementing it on Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: you are not solving a differential equation, not by MATLAB's perspective at least. You are solving a 3 variable equation, so no solution exists. If you just define it as follows, and explicitly tell MATLAB to solve the ones you are interested in, you can find the solutions.

```
syms Xs Ys s
%Laplace transform
eq1 = s*Xs+4*s*Ys-Xs==s/((s^2)+1);
eq2 = 3*s*Xs+s*Ys==0;
solve([eq1 eq2],[Xs Ys])
```

Comment: ''You are solving a 3 variable equation, so no solution exists''. Aha, thanks for this, I was stuck thinking about DEs and wasn't able to see it.